# c# a task was canceled at the await call

Tags: c#, http, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to hit my simple server's endpoint using the following code, but I keep getting `"A task was canceled."` during the `await` call. The server's logs don't show any errors and `cts.IsCancellationRequested == false`, however `e.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == true`. Any advice on how to track down the cause of this cancellation? At the very least, how can I tell if it's coming from the front end or the server endpoint?

```
private async Task<string> SendSingleRequestToDlis(
    HttpClient client,
    StringContent requestData)
{
    int timeout = 600000; // in ms
    string dlisEndpoint = "myendpointhere";
    string response;

    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout))
    {
        //send
        HttpResponseMessage request;
        try
        {
            request = await client.PostAsync(dlisEndpoint, requestData);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not establish conection to model hosted on DLIS.", e);
        }

    ....
```

[image]

Comment: Does it take 10 minutes before the cancellation exception, or is it thrown immediately?

Comment: it gets stuck on the await for around 2min before throwing the cancellation exception. definitely not long enough to trigger `cts`

Comment: i timed it just now and the cancellation happens at exactly 100s

Comment: How did you solve the problem? I don't see any problem with the code. I also tried increasing the cancelation timeout to 5 minutes but it doesn't work. After 100 seconds the task will be aborted due to a huge API response.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your `CancellationToken` so don't implement it. Just use this:

```
string dlisEndpoint = "myendpointhere";
string response;

HttpResponseMessage request;
try
{
    request = await client.PostAsync(dlisEndpoint, requestData);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception("Could not establish conection to model hosted on DLIS.", e);
}
```

If you wanted to use the cancellation token you actually have to pass it down into the client.

```
request = await client.PostAsync(dlisEndpoint, requestData, cts.Source);
```

Comment: i'm getting the same error even without the cancellation token. the process just hangs on the await for 2mins and then gets cancelled

Comment: Are you able to post the InnerException to your question. That might help us debug... but it does sound like the server you are trying to reach is unavailable or you are being blocked.

Comment: there is no inner exception. i've added a screenshot of the exception details to my post

Answer (score 0):

> At the very least, how can I tell if it's coming from the front end or the server endpoint?

You can know it's at the client because you're seeing an `OperationCanceledException`. A server can just return a response code, which you would see as an `HttpRequestException`.

> i timed it just now and the cancellation happens at exactly 100s

This is the [default value of the `HttpClient.Timeout` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout). Set this property higher (or to `Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan`) at the point where the `HttpClient` is created (or configured, if the `HttpClient` is injected).