# Why are only a random few of my Tasks from a Task list running to completion?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, .net-4.8

Ooookay, so this has been a thorn in my side for a good week now.

First off, this is for Framework 4.8 (beyond my control).

I make a list of tasks, using `Task.Run` and a lambda to call an async function that calls a 3rd party API and returns a: `Task<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>`

Number of tasks is 75.

The API has pagination requirements, so the calling function takes start and end parameters, based on the iterator of the loop that builds the task list.

So far all straight forward.

Also straight forward is that after `Task.WaitAll` I get the wrong results, because closures close over variables, not over values. The iterator is at max long before the tasks have spun off, and thus the vast majority end up with the wrong pagination.

**** However, they do all run to completion.****

Now, whenever I try to solve the closure issue, I end up with a consistent result where only some of the tasks run to completion and the rest all fail. I have tried:

- Assigning the iterator to a new variable in the lambda
- Using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and passing the iterator in as a state object
- Variations of the above, but with the start and end calculations moved to the calling function

In all cases the result remains the same: anywhere from a handful to a third of the tasks complete and the rest all fail, usually the former.

The `AggregateException` collection offers little to no insight as far as I can understand.

The general exception is the usual "One or more errors have occurred" and the inner exceptions hints at a movenext failure(?). Stack traces are minimal one-liners.

What could be going on here?

Thanks for the help.

-Willem

**The calling function**

```
public async Task<List<Dictionary<string, object>>> ExecuteAsyncJSON(
    string requestSource = "fields", string searchCount = "", Object iteration = null)
{
    string url = requestSource;

    // Add possible parameters.
    if (searchCount != "" && iteration != null)
    {

        // divide count by 500 + remainder for pagination
        int quotient = (Int32.Parse(searchCount) / 500);
        int remainder = Int32.Parse(searchCount) % 500;

        int i = Convert.ToInt32(iteration);
        int add = i == quotient ? remainder : 500;
        int start = i * 500;
        int end = (i * 500) + add;

        if (url.Contains("?"))
        {
            url = url + "&start=" + start.ToString() + "&end=" + end.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            url = url + "?start=" + start.ToString() + "&end=" + end.ToString();
        }
    }
    try
    {
        // make the call and get the response
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await someclient.GetAsync(url))
            // this calls the API through an HttpClient
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var returnData = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                returnData = serializer
                    .Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(responseBodyAsText);
                return returnData;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

**The main stuff that tries to get this all done**

```
var requestSource = "searches/" + searchId + "/members";

var searchCount = 37301;

int quotient = (Int32.Parse(searchCount) / 500);

var tasks = new List<Task<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>>();

// Put the task list together.
// Using the StartNew with state object to pass the iterator in.
for (var i = 0; i <= quotient; i++)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew((iteration) =>
    {
        var returnData = ExecuteAsyncJSON(requestSource, searchCount, iteration);
        return returnData;
    }, i)
    .Unwrap();

    tasks.Add(task);
}

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    //throw ae;
}

List<Dictionary<string, object>> completedResults
    = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
List<Task<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>> faultedResults
    = new List<Task<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>>();

foreach (Task<List<Dictionary<string, object>>> listTask in tasks)
{
    if (listTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        completedResults.AddRange(listTask.Result);

    if (listTask.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
        faultedResults.Add(listTask);
}
```

## Debug Data

The WaitAll AggregateException is:

```
One or more errors occurred

Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks)
    at Smu.Bbec.Emma.API.EmmaAPI.<GetMembersMatchingSearch>d__22.MoveNext() in [reference to Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());]
```

Out of 76 calls, 4 completed just fine and then 72 fail with the exact same inner exception:

```
System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
    at Smu.Bbec.Emma.API.EmmaAPI.<ExecuteAsyncJSON>d__8.MoveNext() in [reference to code that makes the actual call to the API]
```

I set some breakpoints and this is the result:

```
A task was canceled.
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at Smu.Bbec.Emma.API.EmmaAPI.<ExecuteAsyncJSON>d__8.MoveNext() in f:\\TestApps\\Smu.Bbec.Emma\\Smu.Bbec.Emma.API\\EmmaAPI.cs:line 100"
```

No inner exception.

And this variety;

```
An error occurred while sending the request.
Inner exception: The request was aborted: The request was canceled (System.Exception {System.Net.WebException})
```

This is the full debug data I have on the cancelation (sensitive data removed):

```
$exception  {"A task was canceled."}    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
this    {**********.EmmaAPI}    **********.EmmaAPI
    _accountId  "********"  string
    _authorization  "MTg4NzblahblahblahblahmM6MDNmYzU1blahblahblahblahjM="  string
    _baseUri    {https://api.e2ma.net/********/}    System.Uri
    _baseUrl    "https://api.e2ma.net/********/"    string
    _publicKey  "********"  string
    _secretKey  "********"  string
    emmaClient  {System.Net.Http.HttpClient}    System.Net.Http.HttpClient
    BaseAddress {https://api.e2ma.net/********/}    System.Uri
DefaultRequestHeaders   {Accept: application/json Authorization: Basic MblahblahblahblahTFjYmblahblahblahblahM4M2IyMjM=} System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders
MaxResponseContentBufferSize    2147483647  long
Timeout {00:01:40}  System.TimeSpan
baseAddress {https://api.e2ma.net/********/}    System.Uri
defaultRequestHeaders   {Accept: application/json Authorization: Basic MTgblahblahblahblah4Y2blahblahblahblahNmYzblahblahblahblahjM=} System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders
disposeHandler  true    bool
disposed (System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker)   false   bool
disposed    false   bool
handler {System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler} System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler {System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler}
    maxResponseContentBufferSize    2147483647  long
    operationStarted    true    bool
    pendingRequestsCts  {System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource}  System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource
timeout {00:01:40}  System.TimeSpan
Static members      
requestSource   "searches/17297143/members" string
searchCount "37810" string
iteration   67  object {int}
url "searches/17297143/members?start=33500&end=34000"   string
```

Comment: If you post the exact error message along with code that reproduces the issue, it would be much easier to answer your question.

Comment: Inside the `catch (AggregateException ae)` block please enumerate the `ae.InnerExceptions` collection, and report the types+messages of the exceptions that are stored there.

Comment: Can you debug your code? Changing the exception settings to stop when the exception is thrown might be useful.

Comment: Stephen Cleary, the code is in my post. The errors can be found in either the `AgregateException` or the task list exception for each failed task. I will enumerate them as requested by Theodor Zoulias and post them here as soon as I have some time.

Comment: Theodor Zoulias, I had commented with debug info, but as it was pretty unreadable, I moved it all o the main post. I also noticed that when I step through the code there is a very noticeable increase in successful calls. Normally only about 6 of the 75 succeed. When I step through the code that number goes up to 13 -- consistently. Could the API server be canceling calls because it is "hammered"?

Comment: The exception information is useless, because inside the `ExecuteAsyncJSON` method you have this code: `catch { throw new Exception(); }`. Please replace it with `catch { throw; }` (or remove the try/catch block altogether), and report the new debug data after this change.

Comment: Btw the `MoveNext()` in the stack trace is a compiler-generated method. Whenever you have the `async` keyword in your code, the compiler creates an internal type that implements the `IAsyncStateMachine` interface, with a method named `MoveNext`. For more details you can look here: [Dissecting the async methods in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/) by Sergey Tepliakov.

Comment: Theodor Zoulias, thanks for all your input, which allowed me to get to to the bottom of the error issues. And thank you Stephen Cleary, since you actually provided the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758356/c-sharp-a-task-was-canceled-at-the-await-call

Comment: If you think that the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758356/c-sharp-a-task-was-canceled-at-the-await-call) question is sufficiently similar to yours, you could consider closing this one as duplicate of the other. Just click the "Close" button under that question's tags, and paste the link in the text box.

Comment: I'm too new here and lack the reputation points to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my conundrum.

It turned out to be the same issue as posted here:

[c# a task was canceled at the await call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758356/c-sharp-a-task-was-canceled-at-the-await-call)

The solution for me was to add ***.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)*** to my HttpClient.

Thanks to Theodor Zoulias, Stephen Cleary, and everyone else who helped me out here.

Cheers!